# Bad local variable type when calling save on JPA Repository in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

So I'm using Spring and Kotlin to create a basic application. Sometimes when I get to execute the **save** method on the repository I get the following error.

I have done the same thing in a bunch of other services through out my application. But it seems something is off with this service and entity.

```
 Exception Details:
   Location:
     com/example/api/persistant/model/timetracking/TimeEntry_Accessor_8i288y.setProperty(Lorg/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentProperty;Ljava/lang/Object;)V @145: aload_3
   Reason:
     Type top (current frame, locals[3]) is not assignable to reference type
   Current Frame:
     bci: @145
     flags: { }
     locals: { 'com/example/api/persistant/model/timetracking/TimeEntry_Accessor_8i288y', 'org/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentProperty', 'java/lang/Object' }
     stack: { 'com/example/api/persistant/model/timetracking/TimeEntry_Accessor_8i288y' }
```

**EDIT: Upgrading Spring Boot from version 2.1.1-RELEASE to 2.2.6-RELEASE seemed to solve the issue for now.**